# Browse container file system at rest

Tags: docker

How can I browse the container filesystem when it is at rest.

I'm not looking for volumes or the path to the container's filesystem when it's running.

I would like to browse the files that are on a container, while the container is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

One of the option is using `docker cp`
it allows you to copy everything out from container to the host

```
mkdir /tmp/container_temp
docker cp example_container:/ /tmp/container_temp/
```